# Unable to deploy eclipse maven JAX-WS web service

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, jax-ws

I am following a tutorial from

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jws/jax-ws-spring-integration-example/

But, when I try to deploy the WAR it gives me following error--

```
ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 51) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.SpringBinding#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.spring.SpringService] while setting bean property 'service'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/resolver/CatalogManager
```

Answer (score 1):

The class is in JDK. You should find it in $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/rt.jar

Check that you are using correct jdk (Oracle Jdk7 or later).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to add the `jaxb-xjc.jar` jar to  your classpath. This jar contains the missing class: `com/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/resolver/CatalogManager`

Comment: Given but still the same problem. I am using JBOSS

Comment: I have downloaded and included jaxb-xjc-local.jar and now that error is not present but now I am getting following error--     FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: REFLECTION

Comment: @debnath Add the stacktrace as update to you question.